# I cannot use all my disk space on centos

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, centos

I have a centos 7 dedicated server with 60GB or SSD disk.
the fact :

`sfdisk -uM -l /dev/sda` gives:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 61440 cylinders, 64 heads, 32 sectors/track
Warning: The partition table looks like it was made
  for C/H/S=*/256/63 (instead of 61440/64/32).
For this listing I'll assume that geometry.
Units = mebibytes of 1048576 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start   End    MiB    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1         0+ 61439  61440-  62914528+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda3         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda4         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
```

While `lsblk` gives:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
sda      8:0    0   60G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0    2M  0 part /disk1
└─sda2   8:2    0   10G  0 part /
```

I am really confused where my 60GB is. It is actually showing on the `sfdisk` but not in `lsblk`.

Comment: Could it be that you're using `Logical Volumes`? What does the `vgs` command return?

Comment: What is the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`? `file -s /dev/sda*`? (use `sudo` if needed). Please [edit] and add the requested information to the question body.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be unallocated.

Type `parted /dev/sda`

```
GNU Parted 2.1 Using /dev/sda Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to
view a list of commands. (parted)
```

Type in `print free`

```
Model: HP LOGICAL VOLUME (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4801GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   ext4               boot
 2      525MB   4801GB  4800GB                     lvm
        4801GB  4801GB  73.2kB  Free Space
```

You might find a large bit of space at the end of the disk past the 2 partitions.

*(q to quit)*